# Counting numbers of key in a HashMap in Java

Tags: dictionary, hashmap

I read the **data.csv** file in Java, for the simplicity I make an example for it:

**data.csv:**

```
HAIRCOLOR;NAME
brown;John
blonde;Nathan
brown;Emily
gray;William
blonde;Helen
```

I have a list that contains all the data called `peopleList` *(except the 1st row).*
I would like to get the **number of each color occurrence**

Example for output:

```
brown:2
blonde:2
gray:1
etc...
```

I am trying to make it with a `HashMap` structure, like:

```
Map number_of_colors <String, Integer> = new HashMap()<>;

for(int i = 0; i<peopleList.size(); i++){
number_of_colors.put(peopleList.get(i).getColor(), /*and what to write here to get the number of each color?*/)
}
```

Or am I on the wrong path?
I was sure this can be done with `HashMap`.

Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map number_of_colors <String, Integer> = new HashMap()<>;

for(int i = 0; i<peopleList.size(); i++){
  if(number_of_colors.contains(peopleList.get(i).getColor())){
    number_of_colors.put(peopleList.get(i).getColor(), number_of_colors.get(peopleList.get(i).getColor())+1);
   }else{
   number_of_colors.put(peopleList.get(i).getColor(), 1);
}
}
```

You can do like this.